# How to limit time in AlarmManager repeat Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I use ArlamManager to creat reminder

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),10000,sender);
```

Now I want limit  time for repeat from now(06/20/2013) to two days (06/22/2013)

Thanks

Comment: I am not getting your question.. please explain well\

Comment: you could register another alarm to play in two days and when that play remove the other one.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably other ways to do this but the first thing that pops in my mind is to check the date in your `Receiver`s `onReceive()` method. If the date is < the target date then run your code, if not then cancel the alarm

When you set the alarm, set the date that you want it to stop in a `SharedPreference` and check that date before running the code

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    SharedPreferences datePref = context.getSharedPreferences("stopDate", 0);
    // get the current date hear using a Calendar Object and compare it to datePref
    if (datePref < currentDate)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
      //  recreate the PendingIntent and cancel the alarm with AlarmManagers cancel() funciton
    }
```